# Генерация всех уникальных вариантов комбинаций элементов массива

Tags: комбинаторика

Есть массив например [1,2,3], нужно получить 
1,11,12,13,111,112,113,122,123,133,2,22,23,222,223,233,3,33,333

Можно упростить, получать комбинации только определенной длины, пока делал так:

```
public class Test {

private static void PFunction(int index[], int max){
    for (int i=0; i<index.length; i++) index[i] = 0;
    int curIndex = index.length-1;

    while(true){
        for (int anIndex : index)    System.out.print(anIndex + " ");
        System.out.println();
        for (int i=curIndex; i>=0; i--){
            index[i]++;
            if (index[i] <= max) break;
            if (i==0)  return;
            index[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int index[] = new int[3];
    PFunction(index, 3);
}
}
```

Но нужно получить не все комбинации, а только с уникальными значениями, то есть 0,0,3 и 3,0,0 и 0,3,0 - одно и тоже

Comment: а в чём именно проблема? Для простоты можете добавить в массив пустой элемент и тройным циклом...

Comment: Проблема в том что элементов будет очень много

Comment: Конкретизируйте это в самом вопросе.

Comment: ну на самом деле я предполагал цикл примерно так: {i,0,N}{j,i,N}{k,j,N}

Comment: 1. Поставтьте в тройной цикл ограничение, например a[i]<=a[j]<=a[k], где i,j,k = 0..3 0-нет цифры. 2. Ещё добавьте массив для блока дублей. За вас писать не будем.

Comment: Вам нужен алгоритм или реализация на конкретном/любом языке?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Есть множество алгоритмов, которые могут решить поставленную задачу (ниже приведена ссылка, где описывается несколько из них). Советую обратить внимание на "*Коды Грея*" (данная статья не идеальна, но там много полезной информации).

[Дискретная математика, комбинаторика](http://rain.ifmo.ru/cat/view.php/theory/combinations/combinations1-2004).

Comment: Да, это университетское задание(сам похожее делал несколько лет назад). Автор не знает, что такое "дискретная математика" и будет "сооружать велосипед". Я же ему подсказал, что есть такой раздел науки, который решает "его проблему" + дал конкретный рабочий алгоритм ему в руки. Это вполне "однозначный" ответ.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev, nick_n_a Вы слишком критичны. Тут все вопросы по сути можно отсечь и сказать что они университетские, любой вопрос по SQL можно отшить со словами "ой, это в институте проходят на базах данных, иди читай!". Автор не просил сделать за него, и считаю, что Phobophobia дал в адекватный ответ, указав на нужный алгоритм, который можно использовать для решения данной задачи, конечно не совсем конкретизировал как он работает, хоть и надо было бы.

Comment: @nick_n_a Для просьб, обращенных к сообществу, есть [Meta](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: не обязательно, что автор с универа. Возможно он еще в школе учится или взрослый уже и сам осваивает все это.

Comment: @Phobophobia, малоэффективный путь освоения _Есть `x` нужно получить `y`_

Comment: mkkik, как по вашему надо формулировать вопрос? Я написал что дано, условие и вывод, что еще нужно?

Comment: @Алексей, для заказа работы, возможно, ничего больше и не надо. Для этого ресурса **желательно** привести пример попыток своего решения.